# Inline and Multi-line equations fail

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to write some equations in the Sphinx Python documentation system. I have been trying to get following multi-line equation to work:

```
.. math:: 

   P_{Survival} (L) = P_{S} (L) = exp \{ - \frac{ \sigma (E) \rho L}{m_{T}} \}

   P_{Interaction} (L) = P_{I} (L) = = 1 - P_{S} (L) = 1 - exp \{ - \frac{\sigma \rho L}{m_{T}} \}
```

They show up as one continuous inline equation instead of being a block of two equations. They work individually, so it cant be TeX syntax. Additionally, block type equations like this one

```
.. math:: 

   P_{Interaction} (L) = P_{I} (L) = = 1 - P_{S} (L) = 1 - exp \{ - \frac{\sigma \rho L}{m_{T}} \}
```

only show up as an inline.

Any recommendations what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. mathplotlib.sphinxext.mathmpl was the culprit.